# Why does my pygame show not responding after a few seconds?

Tags: python, automation, pygame

Just to clarify, I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing, in fact I'm really not sure how I got this far. I wrote a bit of code to act as an auto clicker for a Minecraft farm (yes, I'm aware you can use much simpler methods). I've taken bits and pieces from various tutorials and have done some by myself. It is a bit of a mess. However, once the code runs and does the first click the pygame window shows not responding. I have no idea why. I would appreciate any advice and tips and it would be great if I could bet this problem fixed, thanks!

I think some of the code was messed up from me not knowing how to use this very well :(

```
    import pygame
    import keyboard
    import time
    import pyautogui
    pygame.init()

    def Click():
        pyautogui.doubleClick(None, None, 1)
        print('Click')
        time.sleep(3)

    def Img(x, y):
        display_surface.blit(Piglin_Img, (x, y))


    white = (255, 255, 255)
    black = (0, 0, 0)

    x = 280
    y = 10
    X = 400
    Y = 100
    Piglin_Img = pygame.image.load('Piglin.png')
    pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("Icon.png"))
    display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y ))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Gold Farm Auto Clicker')
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)


    Start_Text = font.render('Press p to start...', True, black, white)
    Run_Text = font.render('Running...', True, black, white)
    Pause_Text = font.render('Paused', True, black, white)

    Start_Text_pos = (10, 10)
    Run_Text_pos = (10, 10)
    Pause_Text_pos = (10, 10)
    Continue_pos = (10, 40)

    display_surface.fill(white)
    display_surface.blit(Start_Text, Start_Text_pos)

    Clicker = False
    running = True

    while running:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
      Img(x, y)

      pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEMOTION)
      pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
      pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP)

       if event.type == pygame.QUIT or \
          event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and \
          event.key == pygame.K_z:
            running = False

      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and \
         event.key == pygame.K_p:
         print('started')
         display_surface.fill(white)
         display_surface.blit(Run_Text, Run_Text_pos)
         Img(x, y)
         pygame.display.update()
         Clicker = True


     while Clicker:
         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and \
            event.key == pygame.K_x:
            Clicker = False
            display_surface.fill(white)
            display_surface.blit(Start_Text, Continue_pos)
            display_surface.blit(Pause_Text, Pause_Text_pos)
            Img(x, y)
            pygame.display.update()

        Click()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and \
            event.key == pygame.K_x:
            Clicker = False
            display_surface.fill(white)
            display_surface.blit(Start_Text, Continue_pos)
            display_surface.blit(Pause_Text, Pause_Text_pos)
            Img(x, y)
            pygame.display.update()



 pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's blocking the event queue processing when `Clicker` becomes True.  So once clicker starts looping, no user-input is handled as this loop never re-examines the queue for new events, and just continues to re-process the same (old) event result.

You probably need to merge the event handling in the `while Clicker` cause into the main event loop.  Maybe with an `if Clicker` on those events:

```
pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEMOTION)
pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP)

while running:
    # handle events and user interaction
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN :    # some key was pushed
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                print('started')
                Clicker = True               # start the clicker
            elif event.key == pygame.K_x:
                print('stopped')
                Clicker = False              # stop the clicker
            elif event.key == pygame.K_z:
                running = False              # Allow exit here too  


    # Update the screen
    if Clicker:
        # Click mode
        display_surface.fill(white)
        display_surface.blit(Run_Text, Run_Text_pos)
    else:
        # NOT in Click Mode
        display_surface.fill(white)
        display_surface.blit(Start_Text, Continue_pos)
        display_surface.blit(Pause_Text, Pause_Text_pos)

    Img(x, y)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Something close to that anyway.  Without comments, it's not immediately clear what the intention of the code is, so it's hard to create an exacting solution.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate the help. I'll make sure to add more comments in the future :D